# Error concerning pdftex.def when trying to include an EPS with PdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, eps, epstopdf

I know this is an frequently asked question but the older answers do not help.

I want to include an EPS file but I get the error as mentioned in the header.

TeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, left=1.925cm, right=1.925cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=4.94cm, 10pt]{spie} 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0} % Change to 1.65 for double spacing

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphics}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}  
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}[H]  
\centering  
\includegraphics[width=350pt]{bilder/ProzessfensterPA66}   
\caption{Process window of polyamid 6.6 with $E:0,5$.}  
\label{fig:ProzessfensterPA66}  
\end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

This is the Log:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <bilder/ProzessfensterPA66.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2016-01-05 13:14:19
(epstopdf)                    size: 36443 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <bilder/ProzessfensterPA66-eps-converted-to
.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=bilder/ProzessfensterPA66-
eps-converted-to.pdf bilder/ProzessfensterPA66.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 106.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=bilder/ProzessfensterPA66-eps-converted-to.pdf bi
lder/ProzessfensterPA66.eps)...executed safely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <bilder/ProzessfensterPA66-eps-converted-to
.pdf>.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `bilder/ProzessfensterPA66-eps-converted-to.pd
f' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.106 ...dth=350pt]{bilder/ProzessfensterPA66.eps}

Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Comment: The logfile doesn't match your code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Use **setspace** and **parskip** if you need to alter line spacing and paragraph indent. Those are preferable to making the changes manually with no compensating corrections.